# LibreOffice Base can't find SDBC driver

Tags: libreoffice, database

After installing LibreOffice Base from Ubuntu Software I get the message

```
No SDBC driver was found for the URL 'sdbc:embedded:hsqldb'
```

when I attempt any action in LO Base. Base starts but as soon as I attempt to create a table or form I get this message.
Ubuntu 19.10
LibreOffice Base 6.3.5.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb installed?

If not:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
```

and after closing all instances of libreoffice, retry.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.

Comment: Also worked for me! Thank you.

Comment: @TerryDixon If this solved your problem, you should accept it.